# Change batch file directory in system32 to CMD command execution point

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

So basically I have a .bat that is inside my System32 folder.
This batch file accepts a parameter input, this input is a file.
I wanted it to be that I could open my Command Prompt, and for example do

```
batchfile text.txt
```

And it would pass test.txt into batchfile.bat. Obviously for my terminal to do this it needs to be in System32.
That is where my issue is. Because the batch file is in System32, when executing the command, it changes my directory to System32.

However the parameter I give it is a file. And when the command is executed and it changes the directory to System32, obviously it can no longer access the file.

How can I get around this?

Comment: Pass the full path of the file to the script

Comment: That could solve my problem, but the script I am writing is an open-source program, and I'd like the command-prompt command to be convenient. The point of having my batch file in System32 is for convenience, so I can just do "batchfile parameter.txt" anywhere in my system, I might as well not have it in System32 if you have to enter the whole path.

Comment: Does the script reference any other files that are in System32?

Comment: If your batchfile is anywhere on the `path` (and `System32` is normally on the path) then executing `batchfile text.txt` will execute the batch, but any reference to `text.txt` will be that `text.txt` in the *current* directory, wherever that is. For batch to move to `system32`, it must have an instruction to do so. If it is actually moving to `system32` then your batchfile must contain an instruction to do so - but you've not shown us the batchfile, so we're guessing.

Comment: CMD *finds* batchfile.bat in System32, but it doesn't change its working directory to System32. The batch script should run with whatever CMD's current working directory is. The path to text.txt should either be absolute or relative to this working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Before you change directories, expand the filename to its fully-qualified filename and then reference it that way:

```
@echo off
for %%F in (%1) do set USR_REQFNM=%%~dpnxF
C:
cd \Windows\System32
echo The requested file is "%USR_REQFNM%"
goto ENDIT

REM Cleanup
:ENDIT
set USR_REQFNM=
```